# Do you have to call glViewport every time you bind a frame buffer with a different resolution?

Tags: opengl, viewport, resolution, framebuffer

I have a program with about 3 framebuffers of varying sizes. I initialise them at the start, give them the appropriate render target and change the viewport size for each one.

I originally thought that you only had to call `glViewport` only when you initialise the framebuffer, however this creates problems in my program so I assume that's wrong? Because they all differ in resolution, right now when I render in each frame I bind the first framebuffer, change the viewport size to fit that framebuffer, bind the second framebuffer, change the viewport size to fit the resolution of the second framebuffer, bind the third framebuffer, change the viewport size to fit it, then bind the window frame buffer and change the viewport size to the resolution of the window.

Is this necessary, or is something else in the program to blame? This is done every frame, so I'm worried it would have a slight unnecessary overhead if I don't have to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I originally thought that you only had to call glViewPort only when you initialise the framebuffer, however this creates problems in my program so I assume that's wrong?

Yes it is a wrong assumption (probably fed by countless of bad tutorials which misplace glViewport).

glViewport *always* belongs into the drawing code. You always call glViewport with the right parameters just before you're about to draw something into a framebuffer. The parameters set by glViewport are used in the transformation pipeline, so you should think of glViewport of a command similar to glTransform (in the fixed function pipeline) or glUniform.

Comment: Thank you! :) All the tutorials I used the same resolution in the framebuffers as the window.

Answer (score 22):

You always need to call `glViewport()` before starting to draw to a framebuffer with a different size. This is necessary because the viewport is not part of the framebuffer state.

If you look at for example the OpenGL 3.3 spec, section 6.2, titled "State Tables", starting on page 278, contains tables with the entire state, showing the scope of each piece of state:

- Table 6.23 on page 299 lists "state per framebuffer object". The only state listed are the draw buffers and the read buffer. If the viewport were part of the framebuffer state, it would be listed here.
- The viewport is listed in table 6.8 "transformation state". This is global state, and not associated with any object.

OpenGL 4.1 introduces multiple viewports. But they are still part of the global transformation state.

If you wonder why it is like this, the only real answer is that it was defined this way. Looking at the graphics pipeline, it does make sense. While the `glViewport()` call makes it look like you're specifying a rectangle within the framebuffer that you want to render to, the call does in fact define a transformation that is applied as part of the fixed function block between vertex shader (or geometry shader, if you have one) and fragment shader. The viewport settings determine how NDC (Normalized Device Coordinates) are mapped to Window Coordinates.

The framebuffer state, on the other hand, determines how the fragment shader output is written to the framebuffer. So it controls an entirely different part of the pipeline.

From the way viewports are normally used by applications, I think it would have made more sense to make the viewport part of the framebuffer state. But OpenGL is really an API intended as an abstraction of the graphics hardware, and from that point of view, the viewport is independent of the framebuffer state.